# Sending lots of small packets out of Node.js UDP doesn't send all of them

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, networking, udp

I have a project that I'm working on that needs to send a small 9 byte packet to 7000 different hosts outside the local network, after which it waits for their replies back on the same port and processes the responses.

The problem I'm having is Node.js dgram (udp4) doesn't seem to be sending all packets out. I'm not rate limiting in any way so there might be an issue there.

I'm looping, creating the packets, then firing them straight out using .send(). With Wireshark open I can see that out of the 7000 being "sent" only ~1300 of them appear to be hitting the wire and leaving.

The script itself is reporting all packets as sent with no errors, Wireshark shows a different result, and the hosts at the other end reflect what Wireshark says, they don't receive the packet. I'm using the following to send and verify, packet is a buffer.

```
udpServer.send(packet, 0, packet.length, port, address, function(error) {
  if (!error) {
    successes++;
    console.log(successes + "/" + total);
  } else {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here, or what's been overlooked?

Comment: I think it lost the rest of the packets, maybe you find a solution here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6696

Comment: @C0dekid.php I've had a look through that. That appears to mainly revolve around the receive side rather than send. It also doesn't have any suggestions other than to run on Unix. I've tried different platforms with the same result. Thanks for the link, unfortunately no fix yet.

Comment: Interesting one. Have you tried sending a plain string instead of Buffer, just to be sure this is not the problem? (which it shouldn't be but just in case)

Comment: I experienced something similar in chromium window.onbeforeunload I need to send some udp to clients in a loop over number of clients to inform about shutdown. The send command was very unreliable using a shared socket created on App startup. The callback function was never hit, no errors was thrown. It seemed like the socket never flushed data from its internal buffer to network. I tried several things, like delays and counters waiting for each callback from the loop. Nothing worked. At last i needed to create a new socket for each loop iteration and send. This made it work. Very strange...

Answer (score 1):

There are many junctures where your packet could be dropped:

1. dropped when sending to kernel.  Are you on linux?  Try using strace to find the system call (probably send, sendmsg, or sendto) return value. If the system call is returning an error, I'd expect that to be reported in "error" by Node, though.
2. dropped in the kernel tx queue.  On linux you can check, eg, `/sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/` and see if any drop counters are incrementing.
3. dropped in hardware tx queue.  If using an Intel NIC you can run `ethtool -S eth0` to see if any drop counters are incremented.
4. dropped in intermediate hardware (eg switches/routers).  This is trickier to see, as it's vendor dependent and maybe invisible. You can eliminate this by hooking your machines up directly to each other.
5. dropped in hardware rx queue. On the remote end, check all same stats to see if an overflow is occurring there.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, a lot of excellent points to consider. I had a look at items 1, 2, and 3, and none of them showed any signs of issues. I didn't have a look beyond that as Wireshark isn't showing those packets leave anyway so checking beyond the machine doesn't make sense? Unfortunately I'm still yet to resolve the issue. I really appreciate your response though.

Comment: One more loss layer, have you counted the syscalls produced by node?  Does it match up with what you expect it to be sending?  Maybe Node is giving up or overflowing some internal data structure.

Comment: All sendmsg are accounted for. In the test I just did I saw logging for 7558, strace reported 7558, but Wireshark only saw around 1267 of those.

Comment: long delayed response, but drops could be occurring at the wire-shark layer specifically (ie the bottleneck could be after the tee to wireshark).  You could use the aformentioned counters to verify how many packets were *sent* as well, to see if that lines up.  You'd have to carefully control your environment for the numbers to make sense, though.